# Database queries run after database has closed

Tags: c#, wpf, system.data.sqlite

I am using `System.Data.SQLite` to store my program's data and settings (in a WPF Ribbon application).

When you open the program it prompts you to choose a SQLite databse to open, then it reads several settings (Project Name, Last time opened, etc) from the settings table in the SQLite database.
When the application is closed, in the `RibbonWindow.Closing` event, it calls `SQLiteConnection.Close()`.

Users can also close a database and open a new one.

For some reason, these settings can sometimes take several seconds to show up in the project information view.  If a user clicks the application close button during this process or closes the project file to allow them to open a different one, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown with the message `Database is not open`.

What is the best way to just interrupt every operation when the program is closed.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the Window Closed and Closing events, for the parent WPF window?

Comment: This means that you have a SQLiteConnection opened for the lifetime of your application?. I will start to correct this problem first.

Comment: @Steve I am not sure I understand why this is a problem. Almost every single action in the program accesses the database in some way, so having a globally available connection makes sense.

Comment: @Nate My `RibbonWindow` is set as the `App.MainWindow` in `App.cs`. I have an event on `RibbonWindow.Closing`. I will see if I can switch it to `Closed` instead.

Comment: There should be no need to have the database connection until the closed event is fired. Establish some clear workflow on what your database is thought for. App.Startup => Database Connection setup => App.Run => Database Connection close => App.Shutdown. ... There seems to be something not in this flow.

Comment: @yakatz. No having an open connection doesn't make sense. .Net uses connection pooling by default. Have a google.

Comment: @MareInfinitus The database is constantly in use between when the app is loaded and closed. There would be very high overhead to constantly open and close it. Either way, that does not solve the problem of a query running in the worker thread while the display thread closes the database connection.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `System.Data.SQLite` does not have connection pooling. (At least, I could not find any documentation for it.)

Comment: I made this about a more specific case, not related to application lifetime.

Comment: no, i did not speak about constantly open and closing. i think you have some overlapping region in your flow of control. you could possibly count references of your connection... each connected thread can +1, each thread ending is -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn on connection pooling in SqlLite put `pooling = true;` in the connection string. It's an ADO.Net facility, nothing to do with the backend as such.

If you use that, instead of passing a connection to the thread, pass the connection parameters. Then each thread will manage it's own connection.

If you don't want to do that. Then you have options.

Wait until the thread(s) have finished in a loop, bit crap that unless they are very short.

Busy try again later. Ho hum, user will probably give your app a three fingered salute and kill it anyway.

Kill the thread(s), ugh!

Get thread to create it's own non pooled connection, and then Dispose of it. NB You can overload a DBMS, if you hammer away creating connections.

Add a boolean property, set it when you close the connection. Don't close the connection unless it's not set.

So try connection pooling, it is then.